# statsmodels.tsa.stattools.coint() | Critial Values are Negative, P Value is Positive

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

So I am running a co-integration test and the documentation says,

> If the pvalue is small, below a critical size, then we can reject the
>   hypothesis that there is no cointegrating relationship.

My p values and critical sizes are as follows:

```
7.720961017991229e-07, array([-3.89753487, -3.33674071, -3.04487389]))
```

I have read that in an ADF test, a positive value means its co-integrated, however, is that the case for this test (which uses the 2 step Engle-Granger)?

If the critical values are negative, do we want to see the p-value larger than them? and vice versa if they are positive?

To test this I have made 2 time series that I think should be for sure cointegrated:

```
XR = numpy.random.normal(0, 1, 100) 
noise = numpy.random.normal(0, 1, 100) 
YR = XR + 5 + noise
```

These are the results:

```
1.8668081271228297e-12, array([-4.01048603, -3.39854434, -3.08756793]))
```

So I am assuming if it's above 0 and the critical values are below that its cointegrated? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This would be better answered in Cross Validated Stack Exchange. https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay I will post it there. ty